# SQL Over partition by

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I basically have a case statement that displays the sum of profit and a month to date total for each person. My idea is i want to display a daily figure of that person as well as their whole month total altogether.

My issue is when i limit results to just yesterday (supposed to be a daily figure) this then effects the calculation of the month value (just calculates the sum for that day rather than the whole month).

This is because the total month values are all out of the scope of the query. Is there anyway to calculate the whole month value for each person correctly without having the limits of where effecting the result.

e.g.
The result:

```
08/09/17:    25    
09/09/17:    25   
10/09/17:    25    
11/09/17:    25  <<<< but only display one day and month total
Overall Month total: 100
```

Can this also includes nulls too? I think im almost looking at a dynamically stored month to date value that isn't effected by where clauses.

```
SELECT SUM(Figure) AS 'Daily Figure',

CASE WHEN 
    MONTH([DATE]) = MONTH(getdate()) AND
        YEAR([DATE]) = YEAR(getdate())
THEN  
SUM(Figure)
OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], 
MONTH([DATE])) 
ELSE 0 END 
as [Month To Date Total]

WHERE 
    dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want month-to-date and the current amount, then use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(DATE) = DAY(GETDATE()) - 1 THEN Figure ELSE 0 END) AS DailyFigure,  
       SUM(Figure) as MonthToDate      
WHERE MONTH([DATE]) = MONTH(getdate()) AND
      YEAR([DATE]) = YEAR(getdate())
GROUP BY NAME;
```

This works on all but the first day of the month.

Comment: Ok, i will have a look. Ive managed to have it display the results i want but my main issue is as soon as i limit to a specific days results it messes with the overall month total. My main question really is how to display results and calculations which is outside the scope of the query where limit? If that makes sense

Comment: This result just gives me exactly the same month figure as the daily figure

Comment: @RyanGadsdon . . . That would only be possible if there were one day of data in the table for the given month.  Are you sure the `WHERE` is only on the year and month?